# What does Mousepad's "Open files in: new tabs in a new window" do?

Tags: text-editors, xfce, xubuntu, xfce4

Mousepad's preferences menu has an 'Open files in:' dropdown menu. One of its items is 'new tabs in a new window'. How does this differ from 'new tabs' and 'new window'? I've experimented but see no difference. Here is my screen, showing that option selected (see the very bottom).

[image]

I see no commentary in [the documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/mousepad/start). The source code calls it "mixed", but I've not found anywhere that uses that property.

I thought that it might have something to do with how opening the same file twice works, but I've not been able to do that under any configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Mousepad here in XFCE in Kali 2023.

Open in new tab:  Opens the new file in the same Mousepad Window that is open.

Open in a new Window:  Opens the new file in  new occurrence  of Mousepad.

The two things  (New Tab and New Window) are quite different, but they work as I perceive they were intended to work.

The third option (New Tab in New Windows) opens documents in different tabs in the already new window.

For simple documents the open appears to be like the second. However if you start in the new Window opened and open another file in that Window, it will open in a new Tab.

So the third option is subtly different than the second option.

Comment: You've completely missed the point of the question: **There is a third option called "new tabs in a new window"**.

Comment: I amended and amplified my answer. Option 3 opens files in new Tabs if you start from a New Window you opened. I do not need option 3 for the most part.

Comment: Thanks. What do you meant by "simple documents"? What is a non-simple document?

Comment: I mean when I open 1 or 2 documents .  But I believe I have tested and answered your question.

Comment: You have, but that is a very strange way of phrasing what you intended to say.

Comment: And it's not entirely true either. Files opened from the original window open in a new window if opened from "Open". If they're opened from "Open Recent", they open in a new tab.

Comment: I used File Open rather than Recent because Recent tends to have a different meaning here and there. I like to keep things very simple for mel